# JsonField django.db.utils.OperationalError: table app_order has no column named raskroy_json

Tags: python, django, база-данных

Я решил использовать JsonField в sqllite при django (выполнил замену необходимой dll-ки на винде в питоне в соответствии с документацией, так что ошибок при миграции небыло) в общем колонка в таблице через миграцию успешно создалась (якобы), однако, в бд в соотвецтвующей таблице не нахожу соотвецтвующего поля и ловлю ошибку при обращении к полю модели: table app_order has no column named raskroy_json

попробовал переименовать поле, сгенерировать и запустить миграцию - миграция отработала без ошибок, но проблема осталась

Ниже привожу код модельки, в которой я и установил проблемное поле (raskroy_json)

```
class Order(models.Model):

    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        related_name='manager')
    otvetstvenniy_za_proizvodstvo = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='otvetstvenniy_za_proizvodstvo')
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=150)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # комплектация
    dvernaya_korobka = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    torec_karkas_polotna = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    petli = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    zamok_and_otvestka = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    yplotnitel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    syhori_ygolki = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    montajnie_plastini = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shtykatyrnaya_setka = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # обработка
    bez_obrabotki = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pilim_dlya_transportnoi = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mehobrabotka = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pilim_korobky_v_razmer_polotna = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pilim_torec_v_razmer_polotna_s_zapasom = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pilim_torec_v_razmer_polotna = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    zapas_mm = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pilim_torec_v_razmer_polotna_s_zapilom = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    otrezaem_kontatknie_pyatna = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    kontaktnie_pyatna_mm = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    frezerovka_korobki_por_petli_i_ovesky_zamka = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    frezerovka_torca_or_karkasa_pod_petli_i_zamok = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    frezerovka_pod_nestandartnyy_fyrnityry = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    na_niz_revers_poloten_pryamoi_torec = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    na_verh_poloten_bez_poperechini_pryamoi_torec = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dlya_dverey_bez_verhn_poperechini_plus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dlya_dverey_bez_verhnei_poperechini_plus_mm = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    raskroy_json = models.JSONField(default=None, null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("#" +
                str(self.id) +
                " | " +
                str(self.manager) +
                " | " +
                str(self.description))

    def __int__(self):
        return (int(self.id))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'
```

Comment: проблему решил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему, сам доконца не понял как. теперь и с миграциями работает. я делал сброс миграций в проекте через --fake, вероятно это как то сказалось. в общем поигрался с миграциями и теперь все норм, миграциями делаю, без ручной правки бд